# PWA testing: "Your app is restricted to one or more organizations"

Tags: google-play, progressive-web-apps, google-play-console

I've created a PWA of one of our sites to test internally in the company.

I used pwabuilder and created the app inside google play console.

I've tried internal testing, closed testing, as well as open testing but only 2 of our employees are able to see the app in the store and install it. The remainng people who tested get a 'something went wrong' page after accepting the opt-in and clicking on 'download from the play store'

After further investigation, I noticed this little warning:
[image]

This is the only thing I can think of that is restricting some users from testing. The 2 employees who were able to install it are using company phones and the others are using personal phones.

How do I change this to not be restricted to my organization? I never selected a 'organization only app' at any point. I can't seem to change this to be open to the entire public.

Any help is appreciated